# why is my smoke blocky?

Tags: smoke-simulation, collision

[image: blocky smoke]

Hi all, i am basically creating a tunnel of smoke in blender 2.77, cycles.

i have a flat ring mesh with a vortex underneath, and i have also added a cylinder on the outside (collision object) with a cone on the inside (also collision object) so that i can see thru this tunnel. i run the simulation, bake it and when i render it you can see this odd pattern in the smoke, both inside and outside, probably because the collision object causes something in the simulation. i have tried increasing resolution in the smoke, both in the base resolution and "show high resolution" panels, currently 128 divisions, and have gone up to 5 divisions in high res panel. I have also increased heterogeneous volume sampling step size which does help but i lose a lot of detail. currently step size is 0.6.
this "pattern" is quite persistent thru the animation and looks pretty awful.

anyone had this before?

Comment: Suggest making a small sample file and appending to q using [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Looks like it's the base resolution being too low (does the domain extend far behind and infront of the visible portion?). Try doubling the reaolution to 256 if memory allows and see if that improves matters (should give twice as many "bands". Higher res will use considerably more memory (doubling res will use 8 times as much!) so look to reduce the size of your domain. Also, make sure to Apply Scale on your domain so that the voxels are correctly scaled.

Comment: thanks to both for replying, I will try those things and see what happens :) @batFINGER did you mean make a short portion of video? or upload the blender file itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, applying the scale to my emitter object seems to have done the trick, thanks heaps!